# Why do we need uwsgi for hosting Django on nGINX

Tags: django, nginx, wsgi, uwsgi

Lets see:

Django is WSGI compatible.
WSGI is Web Server Gateway Interface

Now, Nginx is a server. So we should be able to communicate with Django. So then why do we need uWSGI in between??

All say that uWSGI is a server which speaks wsgi protocol.

Then what is uwsgi protocol. How does it differ from WSGI (which is a protocol/specification)

And again, why do we find the combination Django + uWSGI + Nginx ??

Cant I speak WSGI between nginx & django?? Coz WSGI itself means to be an specification between WebServer (nginx) and Web Applications (django)

Answer (score 1):

WSGI is specifically a Python interface, whereas Nginx is a general webserver. So at a minimum you need something between Nginx and Django that translates the standard http request into a WSGI one.

uWSGI is just one of several popular WSGI servers. Others include gunicorn and mod_wsgi (an Apache module which necessitates having Apache installed too). uWSGI happens to be my preferred one and nginx now has native support for its protocol, so you won't go to far wrong by using it.

Comment: by 'now' you mean nginx new stable version 1.2.4 ?

Comment: Yeah, I think it's been in since 1.0

Comment: But then what is uwsgi protocol??

Comment: It's just something that is supposed to simplify the communication between nginx and uWSGI to save having to do additional work handling the original request in uWSGI itself. It's not something I've ever looked into that deeply, I just configure it according to the documentation and move on.